# Excess terms after using the derivative Product Rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I've worked through a problem after a series on the product rule, and came to an answer that was very close but had 2 terms where the correct answer had only one. Can you help me find what I've missed and why I have an extra term? Quoted parts are from the problem's page.

> Old McDonald has a farm. This summer he's been growing a very large watermelon - right now it weighs 100 pounds and is continuing to grow at a rate of 3 pounds per day. However, the market price of watermelon is currently 0.40 dollars per pound, and is decreasing at a rate of 0.01 dollars per pound per day.
>
> In dollars, what is the current value of Old McDonald's watermelon?
>
> Answer: 40

I have $w(d) = 100 + 3d$ and $p(d) = 0.40 - 0.01d$ based on these descriptions.

> Let  $w(d)$  denote the weight of the watermelon on day $d$, and  $p(d)$  denote the market price per pound of watermelon on day $d$. If  $v(d)$  is the value of Old McDonald's watermelon on day $d$, express  $v(d)$  in terms of  $w(d)$  and  $p(d)$.
>
> Answer: $v(d) = w(d) * p(d)$

This is where the product rule comes into play:

If $h(x) = f(x) * g(x)$, then

$h'(x) = f(x)*g'(x) + g(x)*f'(x)$

> In dollars per day, at what rate is the market value of Old McDonald's watermelon currently changing?
>
> Answer: 0.2;
>
> Solution: The price  $v(d)$  of the watermelon on day $d$  is the weight  $w(d)$
> times the price per pound  $p(d)$ . Currently this is 100 pounds times
> 0.40 dollars per pound, or 40 dollars. To get the current rate of change of the price,  $v′$ , we need to use the product rule:
> $v′=w⋅p′+p⋅w′$ . We are given all of these values at the current
> moment, so we can plug them in and get 0.2 dollars per day

My answer was $0.2 - 0.06d$. I first substituted my known equations into the formula:

$v'(d) = w(d)*p'(d) + p(d)*w'(d)$

$v'(d) = (100 + 3d)(-0.01) + (0.40 - 0.01d)(3)$

Then I simplified:

$v'(d) = (-1 - 0.03d) + (1.2 - 0.03d)$

$v'(d) = 0.2 - 0.06d$

Clearly this solution is incorrect, but where was my mistake so that my first term ended up being the answer but my second term shouldn't exist? Should my $d$'s be canceling somehow? Am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: The "current moment" is day $d=0$.

Comment: @EthanBolker Wait, so does that mean my equation was correct, it's just I'm missing a final step of substituting the day I want into d, in this case $0$, in order to make it a single term?

Comment: @Typhic Yes, your equation is correct. You don't need d's to cancel. This is the rate at which the value is decreasing/increasing per day. Currently, when $d=0$, the value is increasing at a rate of 0.2/day, next day it will be 0.14/day, and so on. As you can see, at some point the value becomes negative so the value starts decreasing at that point. Your ideal value then is when the rate is 0, that's where your watermelon reaches the maximum value it can. Since in this case you're dealing with discrete units (day), find the day in which the rate is closest to 0 to get maximum.

Comment: @spectralblue Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @Typhic You can post an answer to your own question here, and accept it. That way the question won't stay on the unanswered queue.